# CPPCheck Null pointer dereference

Tags: c, embedded, cppcheck

I maintain some embedded C code (No OS). I have made some updates an run CPPCheck on my changes.

CPPCheck has brought up the error 'Null pointer dereference: (volatile unsigned int*)0'. This is not in my code changes but I am keen to understand what is going on. As far as I understand the behaviour of dereferencing a null pointer is undefined.

'''

```
typedef void (*pfFunc_T)( void );

/* restart bootloader */
pfFunc_T  pfFunc;

__interrupt_disable();

pfFunc  = (pfFunc_T)( ( *(volatile U32*)0 ) );   /*CPPCheck error*/

if ( pfFunc != NULL )           /* no program loaded */
{
    pfFunc();
}
```

'''

It is memory mapped and the boot loader is first. Could it be calling the boot loader from a different application?

Comment: Well, on almost all systems a `NULL` pointer is a pointer to the address... *zero*. So when you use the address `0` it's the same as `NULL`. And you dereference that pointer, leading to the CPPCheck error. You might want to read the CPPCheck documentation to see if that check could be temporarily disabled.

Comment: Does your program store the entry point of your application at address `0`? If you are dealing with embedded systems, sometimes accessing address `0` is required. Cppcheck probably does not know that and raises a warning.

Comment: So, having looked closer at the memory mapping I think the boot loader is at address '0'. This sits outside the application code (above). 

The above code is called when preparing to receive application software to update device.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are trying to assign a function pointer to contents found at memory address zero. This won't work with a conforming compiler - the C language doesn't allow access to absolute address zero, since that one is reserved for the special case of null pointers.

To solve this you need to have some manner of identifier linked to address zero, then use that identifier in your source.

Comment: To expand a little, the solution (to create an "identifier") is typically done by modifying the *linker script*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Many toolchains also support a way to allocate a variable at a specific address using non-standard extensions.